# Using both ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.16 and 4.0

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I use ArcGIS API for JS 4.0 but I didn't find a widget to add a scalebar to my web application.
So, I tried to use ArcGIS API for JS 3.16 which has a scalebar widget, but I don't know if it's a good idea to mix these different versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix the 3.16 scalebar into a 4.0 app.

You could either make your own scalebar or wait the for ScaleBar widget to be part of a future 4.x release. - See https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/functionality-matrix/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to create my own scalebar.

Comment: I'm not moving to JS 4.x until some of the planned widgets have been completed. Don't want to spend time reinventing the wheel.